# Как перебрать данные из pandas.DataFrame.values

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, kaggle

Имеем такой код:

```
for col in merc_test_clean.columns:
if merc_test_clean[col].dtype == 'object':
    labels = LabelEncoder()
    labels.fit(list(merc_test_clean[col].values))
    merc_test_clean[col] = labels.transform(merc_test_clean[col].values)
    for val in list(X[col].values)               !!! Здесь выдает ошибку !!!
        if list(merc_test_clean[col].values).count(val) == 0
            index_arr = X.loc[X[col] == val].index
            for i in index_arr
                X.drop(i, inplace = True)
    X[col] = labels.transform(X[col].values)
```

На строке 6 выдает ошибку:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Как перебрать все значения в конкретном столбце `DataFrame`?

Общая задача данного кода, в тестовой и тренировочной `DataFrame` имеются не совпадающие строковые значения в совпадающих колонках и при `labels.transform` появляется ошибка.

Задача, выкинуть строки из `train.csv` со значениями которых нет в `test.csv`, поскольку эти данные не будут влиять на прогноз. Тогда будет корректно исполнено `labels.transform`.

Comment: Вы можете привести воспроизводимый пример данных, который поможет воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: Даааа, затупил я)))  Нет ":" после for)))))) Часа 3 искал решение)))) Зато pandas лучше выучил

Comment: ваша задача решается стредствами Pandas без циклов и гораздо элегантнее - поэтоиу и спросил о примере данных...

Comment: Интересно! Данные из задачи на каггл "Mercedes-Benz Greener Manufacturing "

Comment: Интересно! Поделитесь если возможно. Данные из задачи на каггл "Mercedes-Benz Greener Manufacturing ". Проблема в том, что в тестовых данных есть значения которые совпадают с тренировочными, а есть которые не совпадают. Там колонки с аббревиатурами (текст). Поэтому dummies дает разный размер данных(тест и тренинг). Начал делать через labels.transform. Теперь хочу удалить строки из тренинга в которых нет значений из теста.

Comment: все-таки получился один цикл по количеству строковых столбцов (8). Можно было обойтись совсем без циклом, но тогда пришлось бы пожертвовать информацией, хранящейся в объектах `LabelEncoder()`. Эта информация может быть использована для обратного преобразования - `inverse_transform()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я подумал, что лучше постараться не удалять данные, т.к. они могут оказаться полезными:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


train = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\data\Mercedes-Benz.Greener.Manufacturing\train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\data\Mercedes-Benz.Greener.Manufacturing\test.csv')


# get a list of `object` columns
str_cols = train.columns[train.dtypes.eq('object')]

# get all rows for string/object columns - we will use it for fitting LabelEncoder():    
data = pd.concat([train[str_cols], test[str_cols]], sort=False, ignore_index=True)

# encode all string columns and store a single LabelEncoder() object in a dictionary for each string column: 
les = {}
for col in str_cols:
    les[col] = LabelEncoder().fit(data[col])
    train[col] = les[col].transform(train[col])
    test[col] = les[col].transform(test[col])
```

результат:

```
In [216]: train[str_cols]
Out[216]:
      X0  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X8
0     37  23  20   0   3  27   9  14
1     37  21  22   4   3  31  11  14
2     24  24  38   2   3  30   9  23
3     24  21  38   5   3  30  11   4
4     24  23  38   5   3  14   3  13
5     46   3  29   2   3  13   7  18
6     11  19  29   5   3  12   7  18
...   ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
4202  15  13  43   2   3   1   3  17
4203  16  20  19   2   3   1   0   6
4204  10  20  19   2   3   1   3  16
4205  36  16  44   3   3   1   7   7
4206  10  23  42   0   3   1   6   4
4207  11  19  29   5   3   1  11  20
4208  52  19   5   2   3   1   6  22

[4209 rows x 8 columns]

In [217]: test[str_cols]
Out[217]:
      X0  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X8
0     24  23  38   5   3  26   0  22
1     46   3   9   0   3   9   6  24
2     24  23  19   5   3   0   9   9
3     24  13  38   5   3  32  11  13
4     49  20  19   2   3  31   8  12
5     51   1   9   4   3  30   6  18
6     50   3   5   3   3  30   3  24
...   ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
4202  36  10  19   0   3   1  11  13
4203  36  16  44   3   3   1   9  11
4204   9   9  19   5   3   1   9   4
4205  46   1   9   3   3   1   9  24
4206  51  23  19   5   3   1   3  22
4207  10  23  19   0   3   1   2  16
4208  46   1   9   2   3   1   6  17

[4209 rows x 8 columns]

In [218]: les['X0'].classes_
Out[218]:
array(['a', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'ag', 'ai', 'aj', 'ak', 'al', 'am', 'an', 'ao', 'ap', 'aq', 'as', 'at', 'au', 'av', 'aw', 'ax', 'ay', 'az', 'b', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
       'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Класс! Спасибо большое за наводку сделать общий словарь! Так проще,по логике чем я делал. Всегда поражался людям, готовым вникнуть в чужую проблему и потратить на это свое время! Еще раз благодарю!

Comment: @DenisM, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) ;-)

Comment: Только по-моему надо axis = 1 в concat поставить, чтобы они в одну колонку сливались?

Comment: @DenisM, нет, так вы получите 16 (2 * 8) столбцов и решение больше не будет правильно работать...